# Cannot assign value of type UnsafeMutablePointer ObjCBool in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, pointers, casting, unsafe-pointers

I'm unfamiliar with Objective C.

I'm using a private framework and need to be able to change one of the properties from within my Swift code.

The property is declared in Objective C this way:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL *isSSNField;
```

in swift I am trying to change the value of the property this way:

```
myClass.isSSNField = true
```

I am getting this error

```
Cannot assign a value of type 'Bool' to a value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjcBool>'
```

I'm not sure where to go from here, or why I'm getting this error at all

Comment: Are you sure that the property should be a *pointer* to a BOOL?

Comment: `BOOL *isSSNField` Are you sure? That is a very unusual way to declare a property in Objective-C. A `BOOL*` is a very rare bird. I think it's fair to say that, although I have _encountered_ `BOOL*` in practice (especially in certain enumeration methods), I have never seen or used a `BOOL*` _property_ in my life.

Comment: yes thats definitely the property

Comment: `BOOL*` looks indeed like a bug and should read just `BOOL`.

Comment: More information would be helpful. Do you want to assign a value to the *pointer* itself, or to the boolean value that it *points to*? In the first case, should the pointer be allocated or not? Who is responsible for releasing the memory?

Comment: @fluidsonic it was definitely a bug. I updated as you suggested and the error disappeared

Comment: I think I have a better fix, try and inform us pls

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've never seen anything like the situation you describe, and personally I'm tempted to say the situation doesn't exist; I have never seen a `BOOL*` property or ivar in Objective-C in my life (and I'm darned old, believe me). However, if you insist: I haven't tested this, but I think you could say something like this:

```
var ok = UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>.alloc(1)
ok[0] = false // or true
let val = ok
myClass.isSSNField = val
```

However, although I think that will *compile*, I'm rather unclear on what the implications of *doing* it would be. It could cause the universe to collapse to a black hole, so be careful.

Comment: Yeah, you're giving me the checkmark now, but when the universe collapses to a black hole, you'll be back.

Comment: I think I found something better before universe collapses :)

Comment: [SBJson](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/blob/master/src/main/objc/SBJson4Parser.h) uses it
typedef void (^SBJson4ValueBlock)(id item, BOOL* stop);
and in Swift it is converted to:
public typealias SBJson4ValueBlock = (AnyObject!, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void

Comment: @theguy That is a `Bool*` _function parameter_. Those are actually quite common, especially in blocks (as here). But that isn't what I said, is it? I said a `Bool*` _property_.

Comment: @matt A Bool pointer is for any string enumeration routines, both in Objective-C and modern Swift. For example [[NSString enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1416774-enumeratesubstringsinrange?language=objc)].

Comment: @BrunoPhilipe See my previous comment. `Bool*` is common as a function parameter. But not as a property. Gosh, you just made me say the same thing twice. I hate that.

Answer (score 23):

**Update for Swift 5.1**

For pointer types Swift provides `pointee` property,

[Documentation](https://swiftdoc.org/v5.1/type/unsafemutablepointer/) for v5.1 says it is used for accessing instance referenced by this pointer

You can easily set the pointee field

```
myClass.isSSNField.pointee = false
```

And this is same for all pointer types and conversions. If you want to check the value of an Objective C `BOOL*` You can easily

```
if myClass.isSSNField.pointee.boolValue
```

Comment: In Swift 3, `.memory` is now `.pointee`, for the cases I've seen so far.

Comment: FWIW, `NSAttributedString` has `enumerateAttribute`, which returns one of these for use like a `break` in a loop. Confusing.

Answer (score 18):

BOOL* in Objective-C is a pointer of Bool.
Use UnsafeMutablePointer in Swift.

```
var isSSNField: ObjCBool = true
myClass.isSSNField = &isSSNField
```

Then fix it.

Just like the isDirectory parameter in function:

```
func fileExists(atPath path: String, isDirectory:UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>?) -> Bool
```

You can use the code:

```
var isDirectory:ObjCBool = true
var isFileExists = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: <#YourPath#>, isDirectory: &isDirectory)
```

Comment: This helped me exactly to solve my problem with fileExists, thank you

Answer (score 7):

The safer way to handle this would be very similar to @TanJunHao 's answer:

```
var isSSNField = ObjCBool(true)
myClass.isSSNField = &isSSNField
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like your Objective C property declaration is incorrect. Please update like below and try

```
@property (nonatomic, assign)BOOL isSSNField;
```